Capture stdout of Guile system call
If I in a GNU Guile REPL run
(define a (system "ls"))
Desktop  Dokument...

a holds the exit status of ls, i.e. 0.
a
$7 = 0

But how would I go about using the output (stdout) of the command? The function system* seems to work the same way.
The question Execute command-line from Scheme asks how to execute a command using any method. This question is specifically about the function system and how to capture the output of a program run through it.

This question is similar to: Execute command line from Scheme (Guile). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Like the C system() function, Guile's system cannot be used to capture the output of a command. See e.g. this answer for one possible solution.

Thank you for the pointer!
